# sql server 2008 order by fiscal year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to order by fiscal year using the below sql on SQl Server, but I got an error message  'Invalid column name 'MONTH''.   I wonder if you can help me modify the below sql. Thanks!

```
SELECT 'Closed Home' AS STATUS,
    right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Closed_Dt, 3),5) as "MONTH",
    COUNT(Home_ID) COUNT
FROM Home
GROUP BY HOME_STATUS,right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Closed_Dt, 3),5)
HAVING Facility_STATUS IN ('CLOSED')

UNION

SELECT 'New Placement' AS STATUS,
right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), EFFECT_DT, 3),5) AS "MONTH",
COUNT(CLT_NBR) AS COUNT 
FROM STATUS S
GROUP BY right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), EFFECT_DT, 3),5)     
ORDER BY status,
  case "MONTH" when '07/15' then 1 
               when '08/15' then 2
               when '09/15' then 3
               when '10/15' then 4
               when '11/15' then 5
               when '12/15' then 6
               when '01/16' then 7
               when '02/16' then 8
               when '03/16' then 9
               when '04/16' then 10
               when '05/16' then 11
               when '06/16' then 12
    end
```

Comment: Don't do that `CASE` statement. You'll spend the rest of your career updating that thing! How would this result differ from just doing an `ORDER BY EFFECT_DT` and `CLOSED_DT` ?

Comment: In that case, '01/16' comes before '07/15'. I want the result to be sorted by fiscal year and month. So '07/15' comes first before '01/06'.

Comment: What type(s) are `EFFECT_DT` and `CLOSED_DT`? If they're `DATE` or `DATETIME`, they'll sort correctly. If they're strings, consider refactoring them.

Comment: They are datetime.

Comment: Then sorting by the datetime column will sort by the date, not the "MMDDYY" or the "MMYY" representation of that date. January, 2016 will sort after July, 2015.

Comment: I want the result to be '07/15'. So convert the date from datetime to varchar

Answer (score 2):

you can just move your main query into a derived table and use the MONTH column then..

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  'Closed Home' AS STATUS,
            RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Closed_Dt,3),5) AS "MONTH",
            COUNT(Home_ID) COUNT
    FROM    Home
    GROUP BY HOME_STATUS,
            RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),Closed_Dt,3),5)
    HAVING  Facility_STATUS IN ('CLOSED')
    UNION
    SELECT  'New Placement' AS STATUS,
            RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),EFFECT_DT,3),5) AS "MONTH",
            COUNT(CLT_NBR) AS COUNT
    FROM    STATUS S
    GROUP BY RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),EFFECT_DT,3),5)
) t
ORDER BY status,
        CASE "MONTH"
          WHEN '07/15' THEN 1
          WHEN '08/15' THEN 2
          WHEN '09/15' THEN 3
          WHEN '10/15' THEN 4
          WHEN '11/15' THEN 5
          WHEN '12/15' THEN 6
          WHEN '01/16' THEN 7
          WHEN '02/16' THEN 8
          WHEN '03/16' THEN 9
          WHEN '04/16' THEN 10
          WHEN '05/16' THEN 11
          WHEN '06/16' THEN 12
        END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! This is the answer that I am looking for.

Comment: @Cindy  doing it this way will also allow you to add more columns to the inner query like `YEAR(Closed_Dt) as "O_YEAR", MONTH(Closed_Dt) AS "O_MONTH"` and you can order by those columns in the outer select without actually including them in the output..

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 'Closed Home' AS STATUS,
        right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Closed_Dt, 3),5) as "MONTH",
        COUNT(Home_ID) COUNT
    FROM Home
    GROUP BY HOME_STATUS,right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Closed_Dt, 3),5)
    HAVING Facility_STATUS IN ('CLOSED')

    UNION

    SELECT 'New Placement' AS STATUS,
    right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), EFFECT_DT, 3),5) AS "MONTH",
    COUNT(CLT_NBR) AS COUNT 
    FROM STATUS S
    GROUP BY right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), EFFECT_DT, 3),5)     
    ORDER BY status,
      case right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), EFFECT_DT, 3),5)  when '07/15' then 1 
                   when '08/15' then 2
                   when '09/15' then 3
                   when '10/15' then 4
                   when '11/15' then 5
                   when '12/15' then 6
                   when '01/16' then 7
                   when '02/16' then 8
                   when '03/16' then 9
                   when '04/16' then 10
                   when '05/16' then 11
                   when '06/16' then 12
        end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, the "month" column comes from two different date, Closed_Dt and Effect_DT.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you cannot reference an alias in a CASE expression, even though it's in the ORDER BY clause.

This should work:

```
...
case right(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Closed_Dt, 3),5)
...
```